How to run a command after cleaning outDir and before of each vite build?
I would like to run a script (e.g. to generate DTOs into /dist necessary for build phase) defined in package.json before each vite build and used buildStart hook as follows:
// vite.config.ts

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'run-script',
      enforce: 'pre',
      async buildStart() {
        console.log('Running script...');
        execSync('npm run custom-script');
        console.log('Running script completed!');
      },
    },
  ],
// ...
});

This actually works, except build.emptyOutDir option cleans up generated DTOs each time the outDir /dist, which is useful and I would like to keep emptyOutDir option.
Is there any option to run a custom script before each vite build but right after emptyOutDir?
